# C : Does creating a new instance of a value takes space if it exists already?

Tags: c

I was wondering in C if doing this

```
void aFunction(Type* pItem){
    Type item = *pItem;
    ...do stuff with item
}
```

is less efficient in terms of speed or memory than always using `*pItem` in the function, that is not instantiating `Type item = *pItem;`. Or is it essentially the same after compiling ?

Thank you

Comment: Check the code that your compiler produces for each variant.

Comment: @melpomene I don't know how to do that :/ Is the code in a human readable language ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilers generally optimize the code they generate, when invoked with optimization features enabled. Any good compiler will produce the same code for simple routines that use `item` after `Type item = *pItem;` as they do for routines that just use `*pItem` without saving it in `item`.

However, suppose the routine is not simple. Suppose you have:

```
void aFunction(Type *pItem, Type *qItem)
{
     Type item = *pItem;
     *qItem = SomeValue;
     printf("%Format\n", item);
     printf("%Format\n", *pItem);
}
```

In this case, the compiler cannot know that `*pItem` is the same as `item`, because `pItem` and `qItem` might point to the same object, so `*qItem = SomeValue` might have changed `*pItem`. Therefore, to implement the second `printf`, the compiler must load `*pItem` after executing the `*qItem = SomeValue`.

For this reason, using `Type item = *pItem;` may actually be better than not creating a new local object if you know that `pItem` and `qItem` will always point to different objects, because it allows the compiler to load `*pItem` once and keep it in a processor register instead of reloading it, perhaps multiple times if `*pItem` and `*qItem` are accessed multiple times throughout the routine.

In this case, there is a way to tell the compiler that this potential equality of pointers does not occur. The `restrict` qualifier will tell the compiler that the object `pItem` points to is accessed **only** through the `pItem` pointer:

```
void aFunction(restrict Type *pItem, Type *qItem)
```

However, in general, these situations can become very complicated. `Type` might be a structure that contains pointers to other objects of type `Type`. For example, `Type` might be a tree node that contains members `left` and `right` that point to subtrees. For the most part, you should write code in a way that is clear and let the compiler optimize it. If it is convenient for you to save `*pItem` in a local object and use that, then do so. As you gain experience, you will come to learn more about how compilers behave and how you can write code that allows a compiler to optimize.

Comment: Okay this got more complicated than I anticipated. Thank you, I will start by writing the routine then I'll figure out if I need to make the changes or not.